# Error reading large Microsoft Excel files using XLSREAD in MATLAB 7.0.1 (R14SP1)

Tags: image, excel, matlab

I have an Excel file. When I am trying to access a single sheet using the following command:

```
x=xlsread('CS_7_1800_rerun.xls',1);
```

I receive the following error:

```
Warning: See help sprintf for valid escape sequences.
> In iofun\private\validpath at 59
> In xlsread at 187
??? XLSREAD unable to open file CS_7_1800_rerun.xls.
Error using ==> iofun\private\validpath
```

I use MATLAB 7.0.0.1

Comment: Are you sure that excel file lies in the current directory and it is named correctly?

Comment: i put the file on c:\. so where can i put this file?

Comment: try passing the full path to the file `x=xlsread('c:\CS_7_1800_rerun.xls',1);`

Comment: this is my code 
A=xlsread('c:\testdata1.xls');

Comment: is there any bugs in Matlab 7.0.0.1 related to this issue

Comment: here(http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/77036) it is reported the strange behaviour of this function

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it seems that it is a bug in MATLAB

There is a bug in MATLAB 7.0.1 (R14SP1) that affects the way XLSREAD handles large Excel files. The only workaround is to break the larger file into a number of smaller files.([mathworks.com](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1MF35K/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-1MF35K))

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with trying to use xlsread to import a large 6000+ row by 2000+ column xlsx file. So I removed all text from my file, saved the file in the Text (Tab delimited) format. Then I had success using the following code.

```
A=dlmread('c:\testdata1.txt','/t');
```